# What number should be subtracted from

Tags: polynomials

What number should be subtracted from $4x^3+5x+3$
 so that the resulting polynomial leaves remainder $-80$ when divided by $2x+5$?.

Let the required number to be subtracted be $K$.

let: $$P(x)=4x^3+5x+3-k$$

$$g(x)=2x+5=2(x+5/2)$$

Comparing $g(x)$ with $x-a $ ,  $a =\frac {-5}{2}$

Solving then gives $K=8$

but the answer in my book is $-152$. how?

Answer (score 2):

Let us define $f(x) = 4x^3 +5x +3 -k$, where $k$ is the number that needs to be subtracted

By Remainder Theorem, $f(a)$ provides the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$

$$f(-\frac{5}{2}) = -72-k = -80$$
$$\therefore k = -72+80=8$$

I agree with you that the answer should be 8.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f (x)=2x+5$ and $p (x)=4x^3+5x-3$. We have that: $$p (-\frac {5}{2}) -k = -80$$ $$\Rightarrow 4 (-\frac {5}{2})^3 +5 (-\frac {5}{2}) +3 - k = -80$$ $$-75+3-k = -80$$ $$\boxed {k = 8} $$ Hope it helps.

Comment: But the question mentions $-80$, so shouldn't the value of $k$ indeed be $8$?

Comment: @GoodDeeds We have $$(2x+5)q (x)+80 = 4x^3+5x+3-k $$ where $q (x) $ is the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^3+5x+3=2x^2\underbrace{(2x+5)}-5x\underbrace{(2x+5)}+15\underbrace{(2x+5)}+3-75$$

Comment: @
## lab bhattacharjee,  what should I do then?

Comment: @occasionaluser, So, what is the remainder when divided by $2x+5$

Comment: @ ## lab bhattacharjee,  its $-72$?

Comment: @occasionaluser, Right! And u need $-80$ as the remainder?

Comment: @## lab bhattacharjee,  what would be the answer, either $8$ or $-152$?

Comment: @occasionaluser,   You already have $3-75=?$  Now you need to subtract something more to reach $-80$  right?

Answer (score 0):

(2x+5) is a factor.

So we have 2x+5=0

x=$\frac{-5}{2}$

When we put this into polynomial we get k = 8.

So your answer is correct.